# Fatal error while creating Symfony 4 project

Tags: composer-php, macos-high-sierra, symfony4

after running

```
     composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

I get an error :

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  
!!  Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "FileResource" from namespace "App".
!!  Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource"? in /Users/bastiennicolau/Documents/dev_web/my-project/src/Kernel.php:39
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 /Users/bastiennicolau/Documents/dev_web/my-project/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php(80): App\Kernel->configureContainer(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder), Object(Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader))
!!  #1 [internal function]: App\Kernel->Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
!!  #2 /Users/bastiennicolau/Documents/dev_web/my-project/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/ClosureLoader.php(38): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
!!  #3 /Users/bastiennicolau/Documents/dev_web/my-project/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/Deleg in /Users/bastiennicolau/Documents/dev_web/my-project/src/Kernel.php on line 39
!!
```

I've tried some things like changing the `psr-4` value in `composer.json`, and still having the same error after running `cache:clear`...

What would you do to make it work ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to fix this by opening src/Kernel.php and then go to line 39.

Delete "FileResource" and then start typing it again. Your IDE (assuming PHPStorm) will suggest that you use FileResource from: Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource;

This should be automatically added in the top of Kernel.php.

Accept that and run composer update. The issue should be resolved.

Best,
Vess